# extracting text between nth and n+1th occurence of a character using sed

Tags: regex, sed, replace

I'd like to know how to take the following string

```
/text1/text2/text3/wanted_text/text5/text6
```

and get the wanted text, based solely on its position between the 4th and 5th `/`?

Comment: Use awk instead, set field separator to `/` and print the 5th field.

Comment: `cut -d '/' -f5 input_file`

Comment: @HatLess how would you echo the string into the cut command?

Comment: @JamesBrown this is indeed the most intuitive approach

Comment: `cut -d '/' -f5 <<< "/text1/text2/text3/wanted_text/text5/text6"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A substitution command is enough (I've obviously assumed that the interesting part is between the 4th and 5th `/` as you said):

```
echo your_text | sed -E 's!(/[^/]+){3}/([^/]+).*!\2!'
```

where I've used `!` as separator for the parts of the `s`ubstitution command, in order to avoid having to escape every `/`.

More in detail:

- `s!…!…!` is the seach-and-substitute command, where you put the search pattern in the first `…` and the replacement in the second `…`;
- the seach pattern is `(/[^/]+){3}/([^/]+).*` and matches 3 occurrences of a `/` followed by 1 or more non-`/`, followed by a `/` followed by 1 ore more non-`/`; the `(…)` are for grouping a part of a regex such that you can apply quatifiers (like `{3}`) to the whole group (just like in `(/[^/]+){3}`), and for capturing the matching text to allow you to refer to it in the replacement; in this case, the third of the 3 texts matching `(/[^/]+){3}` is referred to via `\1`, whereas the text matched by `([^/]+)` is referred to via `\2`;
- the replacement is simply `\2` (see previous point).

For more details about how the search pattern works, and to understand all of its parts, you can refer to [this demo on regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/juc8w1/1).

(`-E` is a non-POSIX-compliant option that makes the script more readable. Without it, you have to prepend `\` to each of `(`, `)`, `{`, `}` and `+`.)

Comment: thanks @Enlico, this works but could you explain to me how it works please?

Comment: @ZakS, please see the update, and most importantly the **`EXPLANATION`** of the regex at the link.